# If graph is closed, then preimage of any point is also closed.

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

Let $(X,\mathcal{T}),(Y,\mathcal{U})$ be topological spaces and $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ a continuous function. I need to prove this:

If the graph $\mathcal{G}f=\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\}$ is closed then $f^{-1}y$ is closed for any point $y\in Y$.

I haven't really made any progress. I've tried to come up with continuous functions in order to take preimage of $\mathcal{G}f$, but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy if you are familiar with nets. Let $(x_i)$ be a net in $f^{-1}(y)$ converging to $x$. Then  $f(x_i)=y$ for all $i$ so $(x_i,f(x_i)) \to (x,y)$. Closedness of the graph implies that $(x,y)$ belongs to the graph, so $y=f(x)$ and $x \in f^{-1}(y)$. Hence $f^{-1}(y)$ is closed.

Proof without using nets: Suppose $x \notin f^{-1}(y)$. Then $(x, y) \in G_f^{c}$. Hence, there exist open sets $U,V$ with $(x,y) \in U \times V \subseteq   G_f^{c}$. If $x' \in U$ then $(x',y) \in U \times V$ so $(x',y) \notin G_f$ So $f(x') \neq y$. This proves that $(f^{-1}(y))^{c}$ is open.

Comment: I have given two proofs now.  @moqui

Comment: Nice! Thank you.